# extruded Boss/Base error

Tags: solidworks, autocad

im importing my 2D sketch from AutoCAD and trying to extrude base in Solidworks. I realized that when I tried to extrude a shape, it's connected to another shape, and it's extruding together with it whi[image]ch I don't want. How to solve this issue. I have attached a picture of two shapes which extruding together.

Comment: Are you able to share the file, @Pragash Sangaran? This will really help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: dear john, here you go. http://www.filedropper.com/boardoutlinerigidgpsantenna1asolidworks1test

Answer (score 2):

The reason these two shapes are extruding together, is, because in the .DWG file, they *are connected to each other*. See what happens when you zoom right in?

[image: zoom error]

What you need to do in this instance, is either fix your original .DWG file, or simply use the .DWG as a reference for a new SolidWorks sketch. I have shown the process for this below. N.B. I was unable to use coradial for both circles, because, they don't exactly share a centrepoint! This is yet another error with the .DWG - I set the inner circle coincident to one of the points to fix this.

[image: manual fix process]